# Delphi how to create JSON Web Keys (jwk)

Tags: rest, delphi, jwk

Delphi 10.4.1

I am developing a REST application for which I am required to create RSA/RS256 keys and publish my public key in jwk  format service.

Does anyone know how to generate jwk keys or convert an RSA key set to jwk format.

The only utility I can find that does this is the Chilkat suite...

Help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I guess you read JWK standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#page-5

Comment: Thanks. I followed the link and, yes, I do understand its content but I am looking for libraries that will generate the the keys or convert from RSA

Comment: extract from my post :... Does anyone know how to generate jwk keys or convert an RSA key set to jwk format.....

Comment: UPDATE:  
Here is an open source command line JWK utility: https://github.com/rakutentech/jwkgen  
  
Here is an VERY extensive commercial product that (among VERY many other interfaces) manages JWK : https://github.com/rakutentech/jwkgen